# Entity Framework Data is not Saving or Updating Using Wcf Service

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, wcf

I am trying to update and add new data into my SQL Server database using Entity Framework 6.2.0 in a WCF service, and then consuming that service in my application.

While data is fetched successfully, adding or updating data is not working. I am using the method shown here for update. I have used same method in other projects and it used to work. What could I be doing wrong here?

**Response:** interestingly I get 1 in return which means data is updated. But actually data is not updated!

```
public int EditSaveCategory(Category category)
{
        try
        {
            int r = 0;

            using (Intelliventory_DBEntities context = new Intelliventory_DBEntities())
            {
                var cat = context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryID == category.CategoryID);

                if (cat != null)
                {
                    cat.CategoryName = category.CategoryName;
                    r = context.SaveChanges();
                    // return 1;
                }
            }

            return r;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new FaultException<IntelliWcfException>(GetIntelliWcfException(e));
        }
    }
```

Calling from the application:

```
var cat = new Category
{
    CategoryName = SelectedCategory.CategoryName.Trim(),
    CategoryID = SelectedCategory.CategoryID
};
_client.EditSaveCategoryAsync(cat);
```

**Response :**

```
private void ClientOnEditSaveCategoryCompleted(object sender, EditSaveCategoryCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                var response = e.Result;

                if (response == 1)
                {
                    Growl.SuccessGlobal("Category Saved !");
                }
                else if (response == 2)
                {
                    Growl.ErrorGlobal("Category Not Found !");
                }
                else
                {
                    Growl.ErrorGlobal("Error !");
                } 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
            throw;
        }
}
```

**Context.cs**

```
public partial class Intelliventory_DBEntities : DbContext
{
    public Intelliventory_DBEntities()
        : base("name=Intelliventory_DBEntities")
    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AdminUser> AdminUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProductsReceived> ProductsReceiveds { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProductsRequested> ProductsRequesteds { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProductsStock> ProductsStocks { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PurchaseInvoice> PurchaseInvoices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How do you confirm that the data isn't updated?

Comment: @mm8 thank you sir for coming ! i am checking the database, in categories table. i am confused no exception at all, success message still data is not updating and also not even adding.

Comment: You are probably looking in the wrong database. What's the value of your connection string?

Comment: @mm8 i was doing something really really stupid that can't even tell :( but thanks for your time sir !

Answer (score 1):

Add this before `context.savechanges()`

```
context.Entry(cat).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: I've tried this already and now again tried as you told. But it still doesn't work ! Getting success , no exception but still record doesnt update !

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your code segments. I tried with your code and update my database, it works very well. I think the Category table ought to have updated for sure.
The only thing I suspect is the connection string, please check your connection string, and make sure the database you are modifying is the one you are connecting to, and then refresh your database table. In addition, since WCF is hosted by IIS, do not use integrated security to connect the database, we had better use username/password mode to connect.
At last, I suggest you add a breakpoint to debug and check if the code retrieves the data and update the entry successfully.

Comment: i was doing something really really stupid that can't even tell :( but thanks for your time sir !

Comment: i was so stupid that category object i was sending for update didn't contain updated value from text box :(

Answer (score 1):

Where you are calling `EditSaveCategoryAsync`, your `SelectedCategory` object is (presumably) one you have retrieved from the database.

You are then selecting that same row in the database:-

`x => x.CategoryID == category.CategoryID`

And updating it with the same value it already has (or some variant based on your UI code):-

`cat.CategoryName = category.CategoryName;`

`SaveChanges` will indicate that your object has been modified (because you've set a property on a tracked object, albeit to the same value), but when you check the database, it appears it hasn't updated because it was set to what it already was.

To update, your calling code should be something like this:-

```
var cat = new Category
{
    CategoryName = "New name", // or value from some other control
    CategoryID = SelectedCategory.CategoryID
};

_client.EditSaveCategoryAsync(cat);
```

Comment: selectedCategory was the object i was sending from application to wcf service for update. and this object wasn't modified before sending. i mean changed textbox value was not assigned to object :(